# How do I evaluate correlation, that appears non-linear

Tags: r, distributions, correlation, nonlinear, networks

[Directed here from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165293/how-can-i-evaluate-correlation-thats-not-linear?noredirect=1#comment108205947_61165293)

Let's say I want to assess if there is a correlation between two fields, one of which I know to have a power distribution.

A lot of the information I read assumes normal distribution.

**So how should I proceed if the distribution is not normal, and the correlation seems non-linear?**

It seems visually that, that the correlation is non-linear.

If you'd like to see the data, it's available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_CqquGevCafoCIRYbfk3lU9ZimEitNe1/view?usp=sharing

To collect the data:

```r
c3.runStatsFull = 
read.csv("./0962d301-2a24-4cc9-ba3b-90759670979f_complete/RunStats.csv") 
worker <- read.csv("./999ba3af-ad49-4f1c-9627-14b1d4e2cce9_complete/RunStats.csv") 
c3.runStatsFull <- rbind(c3.runStatsFull, worker)
worker <- read.csv("./6135f1e9-da7c-4180-aa53-3e170d50153d_complete/RunStats.csv") 
c3.runStatsFull <- rbind(c3.runStatsFull, worker)
worker <- read.csv("./a3819f79-6ef1-4b4c-9d71-35a2fc380c3b_complete/RunStats.csv") 
c3.runStatsFull <- rbind(c3.runStatsFull, worker)
worker <- read.csv("./db76feda-f5f5-4648-897d-de99027d5682_complete/RunStats.csv") 
c3.runStatsFull <- rbind(c3.runStatsFull, worker)
```

The likely source of the power distribution, is that I am working with scale free networks, generated in the following way:

```r
randomGraph <- barabasi.game(nodeCount, power = 1.2, m = 1, 
    out.dist = NULL, out.seq = NULL, out.pref = FALSE, 
    zero.appeal = 1, directed = FALSE, algorithm = "psumtree", 
    start.graph = NULL)
```

[image: There seems to be a correlation, just not linear]

[image: I know this is power distributed]

Comment: Try taking the log of processing time. That will likely be closer to normally distributed. The processing time variable might have a [lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

Answer (score 3):

**Your data.** To my eye, an important feature of your scatter plot is that the scatter
about (what I suppose to be) the regression line is much greater at the right side of the plot than at the left. (In technical language the *residuals* show unequal variances.)

There is a clear association between the x and y variables, and an important
component of that association is linear. I do not imagine that a simple
nonlinear curve (say a parabola or third-degree polynomial) would fit the data a lot better than a straight line.

**My simulated data.** Here is an example with data simulated in R, showing an association that is not
exclusively linear, even though the (Pearson) correlation  $r \approx 0.976$ is very close to $1.$

```
set.seed(2020)
x = 1:20;  y = x + x^2 + rnorm(20, 0, 5)
cor(x,y)
[1] 0.9758755
plot(x, y, pch=20)
   curve(x + x^2, add=T, col="blue")
 reg.out = lm(y ~ x)
   abline(reg.out, col="green")
```

[image]

Points in this plot follow the curve $y = x + x^2$ (blue), except for a small amount of
random normal noise. [The regression line (green) is also shown.]

You may be interested in learning about [Spearman correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient). It is found
by taking the Pearson correlation of the ranks of the two variables. The
Spearman correlation $r_S$ tends to disregard the curvature in the plot. In this example
$r_S \approx .998 > r.$

```
cor(x, y, meth="s")
[1] 0.9984962          # Spearman correlation
cor(rank(x), rank(y))
[1] 0.9984962          # Method of computation via ranks
```

Addendum following comment: Kendall's $tau = 0.998.$

```
cor(x,y, meth="k")
[1] 0.9894737
```

Comment: Thank you. This certainly sent me on the right path. I was getting a warning using Spearman, as there were tied ranks. Your answer prompted me to look into Kendall's rank correlation tau, which I believe is giving me the results I need. Details in subsequent comment.

Comment: Addendum to my answer shows Kendall's $\tau.$ Its computation is a bit more intricate.

Comment: Thx @BruceET. Indeed, Kendall's Tau is the route I eventually followed. Appreciate the help, (and the obvious effort you went into, in giving such a complete answer)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Noah and @BruceET.
I've combined your answers, along with further analysis here.

@BruceET, the bunching of the data was significant, and @Noah's suggestion of using Log on processingTime was very helpful in that regard.

Spearman was giving me a warning. Probably not significant, but it did make me nervous, and I didn't want to have to justify ignoring it.

```r
cor.test(c3.runStatsFull$log.processingTime, 
    c3.runStatsFull$closeness, method="spearman")

    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  c3.runStatsFull$log.processingTime and c3.runStatsFull$closeness
S = 11385697, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      rho 
0.4534844 

Warning message:
In cor.test.default(c3.runStatsFull$log.processingTime, c3.runStatsFull$closeness,  :
  Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

So I went with Kendall:

```r
cor.test(c3.runStatsFull$processingTime, c3.runStatsFull$closeness, method="kendall")

    Kendall's rank correlation tau

data:  c3.runStatsFull$processingTime and c3.runStatsFull$closeness
z = 10.481, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true tau is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      tau 
0.3146949
```

*(Incidentally, I get the same result, whether using "processingTime" or "log.processingTime")*

[image: Kendall, using processingTime]
[image: Kendall, using log.processingTime]

Now all this double-negative stuff regarding the null hypothesis melts my head, but assuming I'm interpreting this correctly…

The p-value (2.2e-16), being significantly below 0.05, indicates that there is significant evidence to **reject** the null hypothesis, that the data is **not correlated**, so the **data are very consistent with there being a correlation**, even if I have not proved it.

Please point out, if I'm saying something stupid. :-)